# Why is reflection length equal to codimension of fixed subspace in a real reflection group?

Tags: reflection, coxeter-groups

If you have a finite, real reflection group, why can the length function $\ell(-)$ be interpreted as the codimension of the fixed subspace, or alternatively, as the number of eigenvalues different from $1$?

Everywhere leads me back to Carter's original 1972 paper, where it is unproven.

Comment: There are two different notions of length. I am fairly sure that the definition using only *simple* reflections is more common (Humphreys uses it exclusively). Carter was interested in a different question where *all* reflections are allowed, so his length function is different.

Comment: See [this recent thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1512257/11619) for more, and [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1972__25_1/CM_1972__25_1_1_0/CM_1972__25_1_1_0.pdf) for Carter's paper. Seems to me that Carter does give a proof (Lemma 2).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for linking that paper! Unbeknownst to me, I was looking at an abridged version that omitted all those proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(promoting my comment to an answer to get this thread wrapped up).

[This version](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1972__25_1/CM_1972__25_1_1_0/CM_1972__25_1_1_0.pdf) of Carter's 1972 paper seems to have a proof (Lemma 2).

The key ingredients are the fact that the intersection of $k$ codimension one subspaces has codimension $\le k$ and the fact (Lemma 1) that an element of the Weyl group fixing (pointwise) a given set of vectors can be written as a product of reflections fixing the same set of vectors.